Unable to read and write Azure Sql database. Getting exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
I have written a simple .net 8.0 apache spark code to  connect to Azure sql database to read and write to the table but i am getting exceptions. I searched in google and followed some instruction but does not work. I debugged the code and got exception.
I read some info from different sites.
https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector/blob/master/README.md
Py4JJavaError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark
     string url = "jdbc:sqlserver://testsqldb.database.windows.net:1433;database=testdb";
 var tableName = "dbo.t_person";
 var userName = "<username>";
 var password = "<password>";
 var driver =  "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";  //"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark";

 var jarMssql = @"C:\BigData\spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-mssql-connector_2.12-1.2.0.jar";


 var spark = SparkSession
     .Builder()
     .Master("local[*]")
     .AppName("ReadCsvWriteMSSQL")
     .Config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", jarMssql)     
     .GetOrCreate();

 var df = spark.Read().Csv(filePath); // This is working perfectly
 df.Show();  //working perfectly

 //Error To Read 
 var dfTbl = spark.Read()
     .Format("jdbc")     
     .Option("driver", driver)
      .Option("url", url)
       .Option("dbtable", tableName)
     .Option("user", userName)
     .Option("password", password)
     .Load();

 dfTbl.Show();

 //Error To write data.
 df.Write()
   .Mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)   
   .Jdbc(url,"dbo.t_person",
                 new Dictionary<string, string>
                 {
                  { "user", userName },
                  { "password", password },
                  { "driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" }
                 });





 // Stop the Spark session  
 spark.Stop();enter code here


Additional info

.Net 8.0 and VS 2022
microsoft-spark-3-2_2.12-2.1.1.jar
spark version : spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7
spark-mssql-connector_2.12-1.2.0.jar -- copied from Maven repo and pasted to the spark->Jars folder
5.Created Azure Sql database. --  I can connect database through SSMS and do query.

Error
JVM method execution failed: Nonstatic method 'load' failed for class '62' when called with no arguments
JvmException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
Any kind of hints and ideas would appreciate

The issue you're facing, ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver, indicates that Spark cannot locate the JDBC driver class for SQL Server. This typically occurs when the required JAR file for the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver is either missing or not being loaded correctly.
